# Using Ruby Bcrypt with Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, bcrypt

Have a Ruby on Rails app that uses BCrypt to hash passwords, the User model has

```
require "BCrypt"
```

and the gemfile has

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby'
```

This all works fine when running locally, however when I deploy it to my Heroku server I get the following error

```
2012-11-16T14:42:32+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2012-11-16T14:42:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2012-11-16T14:42:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
2012-11-16T14:42:32+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2012-11-16T14:42:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:312:in `depend_on'
2012-11-16T14:42:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
2012-11-16T14:42:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `rescue in depend_on': No such file to load -- BCrypt (LoadError)
2012-11-16T14:42:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2012-11-16T14:42:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
...
2012-11-16T14:42:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2012-11-16T14:42:33+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-11-16T14:42:33+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to down
2012-11-16T14:42:33+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-11-16T14:42:34+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=smartaprofiles.herokuapp.com fwd= dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I'm assuming the problem is the `No such file to load -- BCrypt (LoadError)` but can't seem to fix it, `bundle install` and `bundle update` work fine and it says bcrypt-ruby is installed OK.
Any ideas how I could go about fixing this? I'm all out!

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `require "bcrypt"`? Heroku's filesystem is case-sensitive.

Comment: YOU ARE AMAZING! I can't believe that was so simple to fix, there's a day of my life I won't get back! Thanks so much, if you post it as an answer I'll mark as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just posting this answer to help any others finding this page.
The correct answer is in the comments to the question, by in @eugen.

The problem was capitalisation, as I'm developing on Windows, it doesn't care about capitalisation, but on the Heroku (UNIX) server it does, and I should have used 'bcrypt' instead of 'BCrypt'.